# Where can I find exercises on building a project finance spreadsheet?

Tags: reference-request, financial-engineering, structured-finance

I'm looking for a set of exercises that teach how to build a project finance spreadsheet.

I accept there may be no ***typical*** project finance, but there are a lot of principles are shared in common across a lot of projects. The debt/ equity split, setting hurdle rates, calculating IRR, looking at how yields vary depending on various outcomes, tiered senior debt / subordinate debt / different types of bonds (deep-discount, income, convertible, etc) / equity.

I'm working my way through various books on the subject: Yescombe's "Principles of project finance", Tan's "Principles of Project and Infrastructure Finance", Merna & Njiru's "Financing Infrastructure Projects", and so on.

Now I'm looking for some electronic resources: specifically, a way to start building example project-finance spreadsheets, to analyse the structure of project-finance deals, to teach myself, in stages, how to build such a thing.

Please can you point me at some suitable resources?

Comment: It's possible that I'm wrong, but I think that project financing is off-topic.

Comment: @Shane - the FAQ says that financial engineering is on-topic. A project finance spreadsheet is a piece of financial engineering quantitative analysis. So I figured it should be on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

In my estimation, you are best-served by creating these sheets from scratch. There are a number of reasons for this:

1. You will thoroughly understand the underlying machinations of each calculation
2. You can customize to your specific needs, and so on...

If you are looking for some decent introductory texts, I have benefited from [Moyer Excel Templates](http://www.swlearning.com/finance/moyer/excel.html).

More generally, I would consult Excel/VBA texts as they will show you some useful tools on how to streamline some of your spreadsheets, assuming you want them to be in .xls format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any exercises. You do not mention whether you tried Google. A good set of spreadsheets is on the [Home Page for Aswath Damodaran](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/). You could convert it into "exercises" by first working through them yourself and then comparing to Damodaran's solution (or whether it gives the same results).